# 20.04 LTS HP x360 1030 g2 on-screen keyboard/tablet_mode works not well. input OK, drivers missed

Tags: keyboard, tablet, wacom, input

My first question (never last) is a solution for this situation with convertible, touchscreen HP notebook:
touchscreen always works well.
in the tablet mode keyboard and touchpad turn off - works well.
autorotation display and touch - works well.
on-screen keyboard (built-in) - works not well. 
namely:
i can turn on or off OSK in accesibility. when turned off - OSK never shows up. when turned on - OSK shows up always (when touch or click textbox).

Should be:

if click textbox = nothing happens

if touch textbox = OSK shows up > if click anywhere or touch out of textbox = OSK hide

i found something about tablet_mode problems, but i havent another problems with tablet functions. in settins>wacom tablet i see "tablet not found" - it's interesting.

probably will be simple solution for that...

```
$ xsetwacom --list devices
Wacom HID 481C Pen stylus           id: 12  type: STYLUS    
Wacom HID 481C Finger touch         id: 13  type: TOUCH     
Wacom HID 481C Pen eraser           id: 21  type: ERASER
```

is very much positive that newest Ubuntu supports tabletPC pretty good. with fujitsu T904 (18.04 LTS) was medium supports, and with HP 2740p/ Dell XT3 was multum of problems with that. i remember that 19.04's kernel completely not support touch input in my T904 - i had to downgrade kernel for run it.